# React Native - How to use navigation on FlatList property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I like to know how i can use React Navigation on FlatList property, where the name of the **Stack.Screen** comes from a `.json` file.

And with that, when the user click on that Item, they goes to another page of the application.

**Data**

```
{
  Data: [
    {
      "key": "0",
      "label": "Test",
      "goTo": "Test", <--- Here goes the name of Stack.Screen from routes.js
    }
  ]
}
```

**FlatList structure**

```js
function Item({ label, goTo }) {
  return (
    <Ripple rippleCentered onPressIn={goTo}> // (react-native-material-ripple)
      <Option>
        <Icon name={onIcon} size={28} color={onColor} /> // (react-native-vector-icons)
        <OptionLabel color={onColor}>{label}</OptionLabel>
      </Option>
    </Ripple>
  );
}
```

I've already tried to use `navigation.navigate({goTo})` on `onPressIn` property from Ripple, but a ReferenceError appears: *Can't find variable: navigation*

**Final exported component**

```js
export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container color={this.props.color}>
        <FlatList
          data={Data}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          numColumns={5}
          columnWrapperStyle={Styles.Row}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Item
              goTo={item.goTo}
              label={item.label}
            />
          }
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the problem? Please describe it better in your question

Comment: @Vencovsky Updated, see if you can understand now! :)

Comment: Please check my answer, not sure if it's what you want, but it's a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Read from json file

```
import json from './myfile.json'; // reading from json file

export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container color={this.props.color}>
        <FlatList
          data={json.Data} // accessing Data from json
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={item => item.key}
          numColumns={5}
          columnWrapperStyle={Styles.Row}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Item
              goTo={item.goTo}
              label={item.label}
            />
          }
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

## Navigating

You could use `useNavigation` hook to call `navigation.navigate(goTo)`

e.g.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Item({ label, goTo }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // navigation hook

  return (
    <Ripple rippleCentered onPressIn={() => navigation.navigate(goTo)}> // navigate to goTo screen
      <Option>
        <Icon name={onIcon} size={28} color={onColor} />
        <OptionLabel color={onColor}>{label}</OptionLabel>
      </Option>
    </Ripple>
  );
}
```

Please notice that `Menu` needs to be under `NavigationContainer` so `useNavigation` can work.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :D

Comment: @LeonardoGava If that solved your problem, don't forget to upvote it, thanks